# Scheduling Tasks

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I run MAC OS X. 
So I have completed a python script that essentially parses a few sites online, and uploads a particular file to an online server.  Essentially, I wish to run this script automatically from my computer about 20 times a day.  Is there a solution to schedule this script to run at fixed time points everyday? Does this require compiling the python code into a .exe file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check also `launchd`, it's the OS X replacement of cron (you can still use cron but it's kind of deprecated on OS X).

Docs: [Getting Started with launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html)

I can also recommand you [Lingo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/) app to help you working with `launchd`.

Answer (score 4):

The OS provides a tool called 'cron' that's for exactly this purpose. You shouldn't need to modify your script at all to make use of it.

At a terminal command prompt, type `man cron` for more info.